# Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode' and React Types components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

When i delete the node_modules, and yarn.lock, package-lock.json and reinstall with `yarn`

And run the code I got much errors in the App.tsx.

App.tsx

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';
...
import './styles.scss';

import { ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { muiTheme } from './theme/MUITheme/MaterialUITheme';
import { useAuth } from './hooks/useAuth';

import Home from './pages/(app)/Home';
import UXSandbox from './pages/UXSandbox/UXSandbox';
import { Login } from './pages/(auth)/Login/Login';
import HomeAuth from './pages/(auth)/Home/Home';
import { GlobalSnackbarProvider } from './providers/GlobalSnackbarProvider';
import { Register } from './pages/(auth)/Register/Register';
import { Welcome } from './pages/(auth)/Welcome/Welcome';
import { Preference } from './utilities/Preference';
import { AppConfig } from './constants/AppConfig';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();

  return (
    <GlobalSnackbarProvider>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <IonApp>
          <IonReactRouter>
            <IonRouterOutlet>
              {user ? <PrivateRoutes /> : <PublicRoutes />}

              <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox" exact={true} />
              <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox/:componentName" exact={true} />
              <Route exact path="/">
                {user ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
              </Route>
            </IonRouterOutlet>
          </IonReactRouter>
        </IonApp>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </GlobalSnackbarProvider>
  );
};

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <IonRouterOutlet>
      <Route path="/home" component={HomeAuth} exact />
    </IonRouterOutlet>
  );
};

const PublicRoutes = () => {
  const [welcomeIsView, setWelcomeIsView] = useState(false);

  const checkWelcomeIsView = async () => {
    try {
      const welcomeIsView = await Preference.get(AppConfig.welcomeIsViewKey);
      if (welcomeIsView) {
        setWelcomeIsView(true);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error to key value of the welcomeIsView', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkWelcomeIsView();
  }, []);

  return (
    <IonRouterOutlet>
      <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
      <Route path="/signup" exact component={Register} />
      <Route path="/welcome" component={Welcome} />
      {welcomeIsView ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Redirect to="/welcome" />}
    </IonRouterOutlet>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I use react and ionic for my project

my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "@petch/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  // ... 
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic/react": "^5.8.3",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^5.8.3",
    // ... (dependencies)
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    // ... (dependencies)
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // ... (other dev dependencies)
  }
}
```

all package.json in https://pastebin.com/9p4GuyYj

I think that is with dependencies versions and types, but I don't know what to use to solver

some of errors:

```bash
ERROR in ./apps/app/src/app/App.tsx:47:13
TS2322: Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    45 |         <IonApp>
    46 |           <IonReactRouter>
  > 47 |             <IonRouterOutlet>
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 48 |               {user ? <PrivateRoutes /> : <PublicRoutes />}
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 49 |
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 50 |               <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox" exact={true} />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 51 |               <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox/:componentName" exact={true} />
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 52 |               <Route exact path="/">
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 53 |                 {user ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 54 |               </Route>
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  > 55 |             </IonRouterOutlet>
       | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    56 |           </IonReactRouter>
    57 |         </IonApp>
    58 |       </MuiThemeProvider>

ERROR in ./apps/app/src/app/App.tsx:50:22
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: (RouteProps<"/ux-sandbox", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>) | Readonly<RouteProps<"/ux-sandbox", {}> & OmitNative<...>>): Route<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | ComponentType<any> | undefined'.
      Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>>'.
        Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps<"/ux-sandbox", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>, context: any): Route<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | ComponentType<any> | undefined'.
    48 |               {user ? <PrivateRoutes /> : <PublicRoutes />}
    49 |
  > 50 |               <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox" exact={true} />
       |                      ^^^^^^^^^
    51 |               <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox/:componentName" exact={true} />
    52 |               <Route exact path="/">
    53 |                 {user ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}

ERROR in ./apps/app/src/app/App.tsx:51:22
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: (RouteProps<"/ux-sandbox/:componentName", { componentName: string; }> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>) | Readonly<...>): Route<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | ComponentType<any> | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps<"/ux-sandbox/:componentName", { componentName: string; }> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>, context: any): Route<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>> | ComponentType<any> | undefined'.
    49 |
    50 |               <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox" exact={true} />
  > 51 |               <Route component={UXSandbox} path="/ux-sandbox/:componentName" exact={true} />
       |                      ^^^^^^^^^
    52 |               <Route exact path="/">
    53 |                 {user ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
    54 |               </Route>

ERROR in ./apps/app/src/app/App.tsx:53:17
```

Comment: I think these are types, one the my component that use on my App.tsx:
Home.tsx: https://pastebin.com/bx3Veg9a

Comment: Tangential: I’d avoid parentheses in paths.

Comment: Before deleting the node_modules package-lock.json and yarn.lock, the whole project was working correctly.

Comment: I’d compare the current lock file (there should be only one, but you may need to look at both) with the previous ones to see what happened.

Comment: Okay I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be due to duplicate types or a conflict between types.

the solution is to use the paths in typescript config.

add this to tsconfig.json

```json
“paths”: {
“react”: [“./node_modules/@types/react”]
},
```

Comment: This breaks the live-server for React in Vite. Do you know any way in which we can fix that?